# Debian testing su command does not update $PATH?

Tags: debian, sudo, su, debian-buster

Debian testing with 2 accounts `root` and `ebfe`, after executing `su` the $PATH is still the same from the user ebfe. `sudo su` changes the $PATH to the one from root and logging in directly to root obviously has the $PATH of root aswell.

Why does `su` not update $PATH but `sudo su` does?

Answer (score 4):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/460769

this link will help you.

Debian recently changes su command behavior. now 'su' command don't replace PATH.
use 'su -' or 'sudo su' instead.